# django 'int' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, django

i am newbie in django,i am getting the error on the following code,i guess its very simple ,but i really can't figure it out.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from myapp.models import MyModel1, MyModel2


@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel1)
def test_signal(sender, **kwargs):
    #import pdb;pdb.set_trace();
    if kwargs['instance']:
        instance = kwargs['instance']

        if instance.old_processed_value == False and instance.processed == True:
            var1 = MyModel2.objects.get(val1= instance.val1, val2 = instance.val2)
            var2 = var1.quantity+instance.qty_change
            var2.save()
```

Comment: I think it should be: `var1.quantity += instance.qty_change` and then `var1.save()`

Comment: Read the error message. It seems `var2` is an `int`. It cant have `save()` method.

Comment: its working,you can paste your comment as a answer. @Andres Perez-Albela

Comment: @Rego I'm glad it helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
var1.quantity += instance.qty_change
var1.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var1 = MyModel2.objects.get(val1= instance.val1, val2 = instance.val2)
```

var1 is a MyModel2 object, bad name

var1 has save() method, but var2 is a int valua, so the error occur

what you want to do maybe:

```
model2_obj = MyModel2.objects.get(val1= instance.val1, val2 = instance.val2)
model2_obj.quantity+instance.qty_change
model2_obj.save()
```